# Which optimization techniques can I use for maximizing the sum of minimum distance of each point to other points in a unit hypercube?

Tags: optimization, mathematical-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, simulated-annealing

Let's say I have the following unit hypercube with 9 points

[image]

My goal is to maximize this function:

[image]

In the image, Figure 1 is the original data, Figure 2 is computed using the function, and Figure 3 is the optimized function.

I want to know how can I reach to Figure 3 from Figure 1.

So far, I have tried using Simulated Annealing, but I am not able to do it in the correct way. Any other suggestions would be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You could model this as:

```
max sum(i, d[i])
d(i) ≤ sqrt(  (x[i]-x[j])^2 +  (y[i]-y[j])^2 )  for all j <> i
x[i],y[i] ∈ [0,1]
```

This is a non-convex problem and can be solved with a global solver such as Couenne or Baron. (Note: it will find good solutions quickly but proving global optimality is difficult and time-consuming).

This can also be attacked using a multi-start approach with a local solver (I used CONOPT in the test below). The algorithm would be:

```
  bestobj = 0
  for k = 1 to N  (say N=50)
     (x,y) = random points in [0,1]x[0,1]
     solve NLP model
     if obj > bestobj
        save solution
        bestobj = obj
  end
```

Using both approaches (global solver, multistart approach) I get for 9 points:

```
---- VAR x  x-coordinates

          LOWER          LEVEL          UPPER         MARGINAL

i1          .             0.5000         1.0000         EPS         
i2          .             1.0000         1.0000         EPS         
i3          .             0.5000         1.0000         EPS         
i4          .              .             1.0000         EPS         
i5          .             0.5000         1.0000         EPS         
i6          .              .             1.0000         EPS         
i7          .              .             1.0000         EPS         
i8          .             1.0000         1.0000         EPS         
i9          .             1.0000         1.0000         EPS         

---- VAR y  y-coordinates

          LOWER          LEVEL          UPPER         MARGINAL

i1          .              .             1.0000         EPS         
i2          .              .             1.0000         EPS         
i3          .             0.5000         1.0000         EPS         
i4          .             1.0000         1.0000         EPS         
i5          .             1.0000         1.0000         EPS         
i6          .             0.5000         1.0000         EPS         
i7          .              .             1.0000         EPS         
i8          .             1.0000         1.0000         EPS         
i9          .             0.5000         1.0000         EPS         

---- VAR d  min distances from point i

          LOWER          LEVEL          UPPER         MARGINAL

i1          .             0.5000         1.4142         EPS         
i2          .             0.5000         1.4142         EPS         
i3          .             0.5000         1.4142         EPS         
i4          .             0.5000         1.4142         EPS         
i5          .             0.5000         1.4142         EPS         
i6          .             0.5000         1.4142         EPS         
i7          .             0.5000         1.4142         EPS         
i8          .             0.5000         1.4142         EPS         
i9          .             0.5000         1.4142         EPS         

                           LOWER          LEVEL          UPPER         MARGINAL

---- VAR z                 -INF            4.5000        +INF             .          

  z  objective
```

Comment: Is there any good R package available for this purpose? I am solving this problem in R, and I am quite new to optimization. It would be helpful to know any R package which is good for solving this particular kind of problem.